# Automated detection of deprecated SDK methods in iOS/OS X and XCode 4.5?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, xcode4.5, deprecated

Just by accident, I saw that presentModalViewController:animated: is listed as [deprecated in iOS 6.0](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html), but it doesn't seem to generate any warnings in XCode 4.5 when I deliberately include code that sends this message. I am building against the "Latest iOS (iOS 6.0)" using the most recent version of XCode, but no warnings are generated when compiling. I've checked the LLVM compiler warnings for all languages and Objective-C in Build Settings, but I don't see a setting for warning on sending deprecated messages, only for overriding them. However I've searched StackOverflow and I've seen mentions of [suppressing deprecation warnings for gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622017/suppressing-deprecated-warnings-in-xcode) on earlier versions of XCode. Is this a side effect of switching to LLVM, or is there a setting that I'm not understanding?

(And if not, would people like for me to write a tool that automatically scrapes the Apple SDK documentation and searches directories for deprecated message sends by SDK version?)

Answer (score 1):

`-Wdeprecated-declarations` is the warning you're looking for. Or just build with `-Wall`.

Comment: `-Wall` isn't really *all* warnings; use `-Weverything` if you want to turn on **all the warnings**. Then `-Werror` to treat warnings as errors if you're hardcore.