# iOS Version Checking gives warning

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, respondstoselector

In my app I need to present a view controller. The 6.0 method for presenting a view controller is presentViewController:animated:completion:. I want to support 4.3 also. In 4.3 the method to be called is presentModalViewController:animated:. So I use respondsToSelector: to find out whether the method is supported. But when I compile the app for 6.0 it gives  warning message as

> presentModalViewController:animated: is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 6.0

Can anyone know how to get rid of this warning. I also do not have 4.3 device to test whether it works. I need to assume that the code I write should work on 4.3.

```
  if([myViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(presentModalViewController:animated:)]){
      [myViewController presentModalViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES];
  }else{
      [myViewController presentViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
  }
```

Comment: Ignore the warning, or suppress it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4133201/427309

Answer (score 3):

you could make check opposite for `respondsToSelector` it might help, and this is the way to go actually if you are supporting older versions:)

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentViewController:animated:completion:)]){
    [self presentViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
} else {
    [self presentModalViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can enable / disable warning with pragma into your code, but they are not very friendly to use. And i don't remember the specific pragma for this kind of warning. But some guys here will told you.

By the way you can use a simple

```
[id performSelector:<#(SEL)#> withObject:<#(id)#>]
```

will do the trick

Comment: Its a runtime binding and takes more time than normal call.

Comment: @Apurv no, `-performSelector:` is usually just as fast as a normal method call - it all compiles to `objc_msgSend`.

Comment: objc_msgSend is generated by the compiler, both for perform: as a straight messaging. The only difference here it that is not type checked by the compiler. This is what saika want. Binding is always done dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I had mistakenly set the deployment target to 6.0. So it was showing the mentioned warning message. No warning message after I changed the deployment target to 4.3(which I need to support). Thanks for the answers!.