# Turn Deprecation Warnings Back On

Tags: objective-c, xcode

After creating a new **target** in an iOS project, there are tons of deprecation warnings. **I want to see these in the other targets, too.**

I've searched my whole project for `deprecated` (as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622017/suppressing-deprecated-warnings-in-xcode) would indicate) and I've also looked for `-W` (as mentioned [here](http://nshipster.com/pragma/)), and found that I did do this:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
```

in one or two places, but that's not it. I've looked at most answers regarding suppressing warnings, but I haven't found where I shut this off.

**Where else might deprecation warnings been shut off? I would like to turn my warnings back on.**

**Example**

This should result in a warning:

```
self.numericLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeClip;// NSLineBreakByClipping;
```

Comment: I'm confused. Are you trying to turn off the warnings or to re-enable the warnings that you turned off earlier (so the warnings start appearing again)?

Comment: Are you sure there should be deprecation warnings for your selected deployment target?

Comment: Target -> Build Settings -> Deprecated Functions

Comment: I know it may sound stupid, but did you clean your project, and tried again and still shows the warning?

Comment: @VinodVishwanath yes, definitely.

Comment: @danielbeard checked that, it's set to `Yes` in the target that shows and the target that doesn't show.

Comment: @maddy I'll edit the question for clarity. I need to see the warnings.

Comment: @CodeMonkey sorry for the lack of clarity in the question. I've fixed it up. Yes, I've done clean and rebuild just like every hour ;)

Comment: Is it only deprecation warnings that have been turned off, or ALL warnings?
Suggestion 2: If it's not too much of an inconvenience, could you create a new target with the same configs, and forget about the one that doesn't show warnings?

Comment: @VinodVishwanath I've already created a new target from scratch and it does show the warnings. However, it's not exactly the same config. Also: I don't know if I've suppressed all warnings. It's definitely possible.

Comment: Check the Deployment Target setting for all of your targets. Deprecation warnings are only printed if your Deployment Target is newer than the first deprecation of the API. A newly-added target probably defaults to the newest Deployment Target, and your older targets are probably still using an older Deployment Target that still supported the now-deprecated API.

Comment: What is the deployment target of your project/target? If your deployment target is iOS 4.3 or 5.x then you won't get a deprecation warning for `UILineBreakModeClip`.

Comment: Thanks @GregParker, that seems like it's the answer. Want to put it as an answer? I'll comment back if I learn that it's not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because comments are folded up by default and sometimes get missed, I am elaborating on Greg's comment with an example.

Deprecation warnings are only printed if your Deployment Target is newer than the first deprecation of the API.

```
Example 1:
Using: [TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet]
Deprecation in Apple's document:NS_DEPRECATED(NA, NA, 5_0, 6_0)
Deployment Target: iOS 5.0
iOS SDK: 6.1
Warning: No

Example 2:
Using: [TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet]
Deprecation in Apple's document:NS_DEPRECATED(NA, NA, 5_0, 6_0)
Deployment Target: iOS 6.1
iOS SDK: 6.1
Warning: Yes
```

In Example1, the apple's deprecation document states that the api was introduced in iOS 5.0 and deprecated in iOS 6.0. So although my iOS SDK(xcode) was 6.1, I was not getting any warning since my deployment target was iOS 5.0 which would need that api.

In Example2, I changed my deployment target to iOS 6.1 and the warning started appearing.

**Conclusion**: Deployment target is generally the lowest iOS version that you want your app to support. If you set that to a version that's subsequent to the deprecation of an API, the warnings start showing up in Xcode