# Get Xcode 5 to warn about new API calls

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, ios7, xcode5

There was a method for [Xcode 4.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632834/get-xcode-4-5-to-warn-about-new-api-calls/12633309):

```
#define __AVAILABILITY_TOO_NEW __attribute__((deprecated("TOO NEW!"))) __attribute__((weak_import))

#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED < __IPHONE_6_0
#undef __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__IPHONE_6_0
#define __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__IPHONE_6_0 __AVAILABILITY_TOO_NEW
#endif
```

But that doesn't work anymore because the iOS 7 SDK Availability macros have changed and now have more variances and options:

iOS 6 SDK's AvailabilityInternal.h:

```
#define __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__IPHONE_6_0                    __attribute__((availability(ios,introduced=6.0)))
#define __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__IPHONE_6_0_DEP__IPHONE_6_0    __attribute__((availability(ios,introduced=6.0,deprecated=6.0)))
#define __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__IPHONE_6_0_DEP__IPHONE_6_1    __attribute__((availability(ios,introduced=6.0,deprecated=6.1)))
#define __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__IPHONE_6_0_DEP__IPHONE_NA     __attribute__((availability(ios,introduced=6.0)))
```

iOS 7 SDK:

```
#define __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__IPHONE_6_0                    __attribute__((availability(ios,introduced=6.0)))
#define __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__IPHONE_6_0_DEP__IPHONE_6_0    __attribute__((availability(ios,introduced=6.0,deprecated=6.0)))
#if __has_feature(attribute_availability_with_message)
     #define __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__IPHONE_6_0_DEP__IPHONE_6_0_MSG(_msg)    __attribute__((availability(ios,introduced=6.0,deprecated=6.0,message=_msg)))
#else
     #define __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__IPHONE_6_0_DEP__IPHONE_6_0_MSG(_msg)    __attribute__((availability(ios,introduced=6.0,deprecated=6.0)))
#endif
#define __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__IPHONE_6_0_DEP__IPHONE_6_1    __attribute__((availability(ios,introduced=6.0,deprecated=6.1)))
#if __has_feature(attribute_availability_with_message)
     #define __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__IPHONE_6_0_DEP__IPHONE_6_1_MSG(_msg)    __attribute__((availability(ios,introduced=6.0,deprecated=6.1,message=_msg)))
#else
     #define __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__IPHONE_6_0_DEP__IPHONE_6_1_MSG(_msg)    __attribute__((availability(ios,introduced=6.0,deprecated=6.1)))
#endif
#define __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__IPHONE_6_0_DEP__IPHONE_7_0    __attribute__((availability(ios,introduced=6.0,deprecated=7.0)))
#if __has_feature(attribute_availability_with_message)
     #define __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__IPHONE_6_0_DEP__IPHONE_7_0_MSG(_msg)    __attribute__((availability(ios,introduced=6.0,deprecated=7.0,message=_msg)))
#else
     #define __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__IPHONE_6_0_DEP__IPHONE_7_0_MSG(_msg)    __attribute__((availability(ios,introduced=6.0,deprecated=7.0)))
#endif
#define __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__IPHONE_6_0_DEP__IPHONE_NA               __attribute__((availability(ios,introduced=6.0)))
#define __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__IPHONE_6_0_DEP__IPHONE_NA_MSG(_msg)     __attribute__((availability(ios,introduced=6.0)))
```

Could it be that Xcode 5 has the `attribute_availability_with_message` feature so the old macro redefinition is no longer used?

Also it would be cool to print more than the "TOO NEW!" message with all the new introduced/deprecated information.

**Edit:**

Most definitions in iOS 7 SDK moved from `__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(_ios)`/`__AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL##_ios` to `NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(_ios)`/`CF_AVAILABLE_IOS(_ios)`, so redefining:

```
#undef NS_AVAILABLE_IOS
#define NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(_ios) __attribute__((availability(ios,__NSi_##_ios))) __attribute__((deprecated("TOO NEW!")))
```

Should work. And actually it does because Xcode 5 autocompletion shows the methods as deprecated.

Building however doesn't trigger any warning despite having the `GCC_WARN_ABOUT_DEPRECATED_FUNCTIONS` build option on...

Comment: Is there a `__AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__IPHONE_7_0` ?

Comment: Then my answer might work.  Try it out.

Comment: It kinda works. See edit note.

Comment: Try "unavailable" instead of "deprecated" for the attribute.

Comment: First off I know now why Xcode doesn't trigger those deprecations warnings http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18197326/turn-deprecation-warnings-back-on. As for unavailable it has the same result.

Comment: If you want warnings for too new APIs (i.e. you want to build for iOS 6) set your SDK to iOS 6 in Xcode settings. You won't be able to use any new APIs (except via soft linking).

Comment: @nielsbot: It works but then one has to import the iOS 6 SDK into Xcode 5 first. Also it shows up as an error and not a warning, so too many of them would stop the build.

Comment: If you want your code to run on iOS 6, then any direct use of iOS 7 APIs _is_ an error. You have to write your code so that you do not use iOS 7 APIs. Yes--You will have to install the iOS 6 SDK. Depends if you're trying to make an iOS 6 compatible app or not.

Comment: @nielsbot Using newer API calls is not an error if you're careful to dynamically check the running version (`[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]`).

Comment: Or when using e.g. `respondsToSelector:`... generally better than `[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]` where possible

Comment: Did you have any information for Xcode 6?

Comment: I have just tried this with Xcode 7.3 and it doesn't seem to work. I will changing some project's build parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>As of Xcode 5.0 it is not possible to get warnings from new API calls by redefining macros.</s>

Redefining a macro does show up in autocompletion and preprocessed preview (Assistant Editor > Preprocess) but does not trigger a warning despite using `deprecate` or `unavailable` keywords.

Xcode 5.0.1+ does show a warning so both `__AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__IPHONE_X_X` and `NS_AVAILABLE_IOS` can now be redefined as mentioned in the question and @borrrden answer.

Code available as a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/rivera-ernesto/7228433) and as a [library](https://github.com/CyberAgent/iOS-NBUCore/blob/master/Source/NBUAvailability.h):

```
#define __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_SOFT_MAX_REQUIRED __IPHONE_5_0

#ifndef __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_SOFT_MAX_REQUIRED
    #define __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_SOFT_MAX_REQUIRED __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED
#endif

#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_SOFT_MAX_REQUIRED < __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED
    #error You cannot ask for a soft max version which is less than the deployment target
#endif

#define __NBU_AVAILABILITY_STARTING(version) __attribute__((deprecated("Only available in iOS " version "+"))) __attribute__((weak_import))

#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_SOFT_MAX_REQUIRED < __IPHONE_2_0
    #undef  __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__IPHONE_2_0
    #define __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__IPHONE_2_0 __NBU_AVAILABILITY_STARTING("2.0")
    #define __NBU_APICHECK_2_0(_ios)            __NBU_AVAILABILITY_STARTING("2.0")
#else
    #define __NBU_APICHECK_2_0(_ios)            CF_AVAILABLE_IOS(_ios)
#endif

#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_SOFT_MAX_REQUIRED < __IPHONE_2_1
    #undef  __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__IPHONE_2_1
    #define __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__IPHONE_2_1 __NBU_AVAILABILITY_STARTING("2.1")
    #define __NBU_APICHECK_2_1(_ios)            __NBU_AVAILABILITY_STARTING("2.1")
#else
    #define __NBU_APICHECK_2_1(_ios)            CF_AVAILABLE_IOS(_ios)
#endif

//...

#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_SOFT_MAX_REQUIRED < __IPHONE_7_0
    #undef  __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__IPHONE_7_0
    #define __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__IPHONE_7_0 __NBU_AVAILABILITY_STARTING("7.0")
    #define __NBU_APICHECK_7_0(_ios)            __NBU_AVAILABILITY_STARTING("7.0")
#else
    #define __NBU_APICHECK_7_0(_ios)            CF_AVAILABLE_IOS(_ios)
#endif

#undef  NS_AVAILABLE_IOS
#define NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(_ios)                  __NBU_APICHECK_##_ios( _ios )

#undef  __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED
#define __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(_osx, _osxDep, _ios, _iosDep)            __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL##_ios

#undef  __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED_MSG
#define __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED_MSG(_osx, _osxDep, _ios, _iosDep, _msg)  __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL##_ios
```

Answer (score 1):

I found some other information on the topic.  This will redefine a different macro (`NS_AVAILABLE_IOS`).  Perhaps it will work a bit better than

(Source https://www.albertopasca.it/whiletrue/xcode-warn-about-new-api-classes-and-methods/)

```
#import <availability.h>
#import <foundation/NSObjCRuntime.h>

#if( 1 )

#define APICHECK_2_0( _ios ) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA, __IPHONE_##_ios)
#define APICHECK_2_1( _ios ) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA, __IPHONE_##_ios)
#define APICHECK_2_2( _ios ) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA, __IPHONE_##_ios)
#define APICHECK_3_0( _ios ) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA, __IPHONE_##_ios)
#define APICHECK_3_1( _ios ) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA, __IPHONE_##_ios)
#define APICHECK_3_2( _ios ) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA, __IPHONE_##_ios)
#define APICHECK_4_0( _ios ) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA, __IPHONE_##_ios)
#define APICHECK_4_1( _ios ) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA, __IPHONE_##_ios)
#define APICHECK_4_2( _ios ) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA, __IPHONE_##_ios)
#define APICHECK_4_3( _ios ) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA, __IPHONE_##_ios)
#define APICHECK_5_0( _ios ) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA, __IPHONE_##_ios)
#define APICHECK_5_1( _ios ) __attribute__((deprecated("UNAVAILABLE PRIOR TO 5.1")))
#define APICHECK_6_0( _ios ) __attribute__((deprecated("UNAVAILABLE PRIOR TO 6.0")))
#define APICHECK_6_1( _ios ) __attribute__((deprecated("UNAVAILABLE PRIOR TO 6.1")))
#define APICHECK_NA( _ios )  __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA, __IPHONE_##_ios)

#undef NS_AVAILABLE_IOS
#define NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(_ios) APICHECK_ ## _ios( _ios )

#undef NS_AVAILABLE
#define NS_AVAILABLE(_mac, _ios) APICHECK_ ## _ios( _ios )

#endif
```

You can use conditionals the same way as before (`#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED < __IPHONE_6_0` etc).  Note that I have not tested this because I don't have Xcode 5 on my machine yet.  If you want to turn the warnings into errors you can use `__attribute__((unavailable("UNAVAILABLE PRIOR TO 6.1")))` etc.

You can also try using this program, though it is paid.  http://www.deploymateapp.com/

Comment: Thanks this helped me but also `__AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL` is still in some places.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 5, you should be able to use/adapt the code from my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/19567669/473067. It could be incompatible with the use of modules, though, I haven't checked.

I posted a summary here: http://iphone.m20.nl/wp/2013/10/xcode-5-and-flagging-weak-linked-unavailable-symbols-from-a-newer-sdk/

Answer (score 0):

Use the method described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8919108/480467

In addition, to get this to work under XCode 5 you need to also redefine the NS_AVAILABLE and NS_DEPRECATED macros because CFAvailability.h distinguishes between compilers that support the attribute_availability_with_message feature.

See my response here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19704587/480467

Comment: `NS_AVAILABLE` uses `CF_AVAILABLE` so it suffices to redefine the former. As for deprecations I just redefined `__OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED ` and `__OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED_MSG` because this code is only meant to be commented out most of the time and only serves to check the currently available (but too new) API calls. Thanks, I updated the answer as well.