# Show Compile Warning if Framework is not added

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, compiler-construction, warnings

in objective c we can create our warnings.

In my case , requirement is if framework is not available i want to show my warning at the compile time.

is there any way ?

I tried

```
 # define BOOL isFrameworkLoaded = (NSClassFromString(@"SystemConfiguration") != nil);

  #ifdef isFrameworkLoaded  
  #else  
  #warning @"Add System Configuration Framework"  
  #endif
```

but getting no result.

Comment: You seem to be a little fuzzy on what you are able to do at compile time.  What is your definition of "Unavailable?"  If you mean unavailable to the lowest targeted version, then you can try this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19111934/get-xcode-5-to-warn-about-new-api-calls

Comment: Unavailable - if i don't add framework from my target , i want to show a warning.

Comment: That is not possible.  But you will get an error at compile time anyway if you don't link to the correct library and try to use it.

Comment: A previous version of AFNetworking had this:`#ifndef __UTTYPE__
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED
#warning MobileCoreServices framework not found in project, or not included in precompiled header. etc.
#else
#warning CoreServices framework not found in project, etc.
#endif
#endif`

Comment: humm, but key for that __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED  like isFrameworkLoaded