# Change UISearchBar text color in iOS 9+

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uikit, uisearchbar

In iOS 7.x we were able to use

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil]
    setDefaultTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:myColor}];
```

But it got deprecated in iOS 9. The only solution I know - is to iterate through subview hierarchy of `UISearchBar`, look for `UITextField` and change its properties. But this way is considered as **Private API Usage**

Do we have **legal** way to change UISearchBar text color in iOS 9.x?

Comment: Just because it's deprecated doesn't mean you can't use it (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4133201/4062250 if you are annoyed by the warning).

Comment: There is no such method at all, at least in Swift `UIAppearance` protocol doesn't contain such method: https://gist.github.com/OgreSwamp/d554536d8f747d618483

Comment: Didn't thought of that... Maybe this will help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24136874/appearancewhencontainedin-in-swift

Comment: Iterating subview hierarchy is not using private API at all. You are safe to do so. The only problem of this is the hierarchy can be changed any time.

Answer (score 1):

You now need to use appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:

For example:

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UISearchBar class]]] setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```